# Press a button to sum a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, metrics, excel-charts

In column (T2) going down I have the category "money spent". In the next column (U2) I have the date "mm/dd/yy". I want to take the money spent between two dates, sum them up and display it in a message box. How do I do this?

My code so far is:

```
Sub Button()
Dim myRange 
Dim Results
Dim Run As Long 
myRange = Worksheet("sheet1").Range ("T2", "5")
Results = WorksheetFunction.Sum(myrange) 
MsgBox (Results) 
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know which two dates?

Comment: I can enter the cell number with the value I want

Answer (score 1):

This will prompt you for two single cell date selections, and then offset to get the total. This is assuming the dates you select are in Column U so it can add up values in Column T. If you are planning on entering dates into another cell you will need to use find or something to do get the range.

If you want to use a button just assign the Sub.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateTotal()
    Dim startrange As Range
    Dim endrange As Range
    
    
    On Error GoTo errhandler
    
    Dim dateselected As Boolean
    dateselected = False
    'Make sure one date per range is selected
    Do Until dateselected = True
        Set startrange = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Single Cell Starting Date Range", , , , , , , 8)
        Set endrange = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Single Cell Ending Date Range", , , , , , , 8)
        If IsDate(startrange.Value) And IsDate(endrange.Value) Then
            dateselected = True
        End If
    Loop
    
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim daterange As Range
        Set daterange = .Range(startrange, endrange) 'Combine Ranges
        Dim cell As Range
        Dim total As Double
        total = 0
        For Each cell In daterange.Offset(0, -1)
            total = total + cell.Value ' Get Total
        Next cell
        MsgBox "Total value of daterange: " & total
    End With
    Exit Sub
errhandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 424 ' Add in other cases as needed
            MsgBox "Range selection cancelled, Exiting"
            Exit Sub
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Unhandled error: " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & Err.Description
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```